# Centering inside sidewaysfigure with footnote

Tags: graphics, floats, rotating

I am using `sidewaysfigure` environment to rotate my figures. However, they are not centered in the middle of the page. I can't use `\centering` since I want that my footnote is "left aligned".

Here is a short example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{rotating}
 \usepackage{float}


\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\caption{Fill}
 \includegraphics[width=0.9\paperwidth]{example-image-c}
 \footnotesize 

 A long footnote
  \label{fig:fill}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

The output of my "real example" with the code mentioned in the comments:

[image]

The caption should be aligned in the same height as the footnote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve centering, or to overcome `\centering`. Centering is achieved by setting `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` to `\hfil` (more of less). You can also center an image by adding `\hfil` to the left (and `\par` to the right), or `\hfill` before and after. One can overcome `\centering` using `\parbox{\linewidth}{...}` or `\makebox[\linewidth][l]{...}`.

BTW, inserting `\hfil` between subfigures has a nice effect too.

You also might consider using afterpage and pdflscape instead of sidewaysfigure (It displays the page so that the image is right-side-up.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{rotating}
 \usepackage{float}
\usepackage[format=plain, justification=RaggedRight, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\caption{Fill}\label{fig:fill}
\hfil\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-c}% center inamge only

\footnotesize A long footnote
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\caption{Fill}\label{fig:fill}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\parbox{\linewidth}{\footnotesize A long footnote}% justify footnote
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Measure the image and use a suitably sized `tabular`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{rotating}

\newsavebox{\imagebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\caption{Fill}\label{fig:fill}

\sbox{\imagebox}{\includegraphics[width=0.9\paperwidth]{example-image-c}}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\wd\imagebox}@{}}
\usebox{\imagebox} \\
\footnotesize  A long footnote, long footnote, long footnote,
long footnote, long footnote, long footnote, long footnote,
long footnote, long footnote, long footnote, long footnote,
long footnote, long footnote
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the `\label` refers to `\caption`, so it's best placed near it.

A different realization with the caption left aligned with respect to the image:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[
  format=plain,
  justification=RaggedRight,
  singlelinecheck=false
]{caption}

\newsavebox{\imagebox}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering

\sbox{\imagebox}{\includegraphics[width=0.9\paperwidth]{example-image-c}}

\begin{minipage}{\wd\imagebox}
\caption{Fill}\label{fig:fill}

\usebox{\imagebox}

\footnotesize  A long footnote, long footnote, long footnote,
long footnote, long footnote, long footnote, long footnote,
long footnote, long footnote, long footnote, long footnote,
long footnote, long footnote

\end{minipage}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works partially. The caption is now too "left aligned". I'll add the output of my real example. My caption options are:\usepackage[format=plain,
justification=RaggedRight,  singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

Comment: @Vala Added code for your setup.